# How to do syncronized playback using AVAudioPlayer API?

Tags: xamarin, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avkit

There is an example here on using AVAudioPlayer. In the description it says it's able to:

- Play multiple sounds at the same time with optional synchronization.

I don't see how to do that in the example.

Apple API that says the same thing:

- Play multiple sounds simultaneously by synchronizing the playback of multiple players

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayer?language=objc

Example:
https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer

**Note**: The repository is archived and does not allow adding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the playAtTime() method on all the sounds you want and pass in the same date to all the sounds to play at the same time.

I read about the playAtTime() method and thought it was "play at this position in time of the sound" BECAUSE IT SAYS IT SAYS THE PARAMETER IS NAMED TIME NOT DATE:

[image]

but it actually takes a Date and that means play at a future date and time.

So if you were only looking at the auto complete API and it says `playAtTime(time)` you don't get the details you do when looking at the documentation. Seeing that there is another property on sound player that is currentTime that is a number and not a date.

[image]

Documentation:

> Plays audio asynchronously, starting at a specified point in the audio
> output device’s timeline.

```
func startSynchronizedPlayback() {
    // Create a time offset relative to the current device time.
    let timeOffset = playerOne.deviceCurrentTime + 0.01
    
    // Start playback of both players at the same time.
    playerOne.play(atTime: timeOffset)
    playerTwo.play(atTime: timeOffset)
}
```